# What are the options to avoid carrying USB media back and forth between my TV and laptop?

Tags: usb, nas, tv

I have a Samsung C650 40" TV. It has USB ports from which it can play movies. It also has an Ethernet port but it seems that it cannot do samba nor NFS, only DLNA but then I will get a very bad FFD/REW experience.

So, besides DLNA, what are the other options?

(For example, would USB-to-USB transfer cables work? Or perhaps there is some kind of hard drive box available that has both Ethernet and USB sockets and actually works when both are connected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WD Live TV](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=330) is an option. And you can use multiple HDs with it :)

Comment: Btw, are you sure that I can copy movies onto it through network while it's connected to the tv via usb?

Comment: You should connect WD Live TV via HDMI to your TV and from the looks of it you can attach NAS to it but I would go with a portable hard drive or other USB storage device with supported video or audio content stored on it. And use the Ethernet port for streaming i.e. YouTube.

Comment: Why would you go with a portable hard drive? Since my TV supports playing media straight from a USB device, why would I need the WD Live TV then? This is what I'm doing right now: detaching the portable hard drive, carrying it to my study room where the laptop is, attaching it, refreshing content and then take it back to TV.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that would free me from carrying a portable media back and forth my TV and laptop.

Comment: @Henno - The most common practice here is to have NAS and attaching it to the WD Live TV. When you have NAS and well built home network it takes most of the troubles away. What I said in previous comment was my personal choice....

Comment: If you do it for the exercise, I might get it. :)

Comment: I wish I could do that but since I do not own WD Live TV I cannot. Out of curiosity, can your network reach the TV? Do you have NAS?

Comment: The TV is connected to the network. It can find and download Samsung firmware upgrades from the Internet and I can stream videos from my phone via wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got a Samsung TV, [Vuze should work](http://www.vuze.com/features/device). You can also use [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/) with an Xbox 360, PS3, or TiVo.

Comment: Vuze does DLNA which Henno rejected in the question.